# Scala finding the last element in a Map list

Tags: scala, mapping

My system allows a user to search through a list of "Stock" datas to display data for each. Currently they can search for the minimum in a stock list and the maximum ints. I am trying to make it so they can find the "Current" stock prices, so the last element of the tail of the list. 
I had this previously, However this does not conform to my mapped list;

```
// last element
  def lastif(ls:List[Int]):Int = {
    if(ls.tail == Nil)
      ls.head
    else
      lastif(ls.tail)
  }
```

This is what I have, including what does not work at the bottom

```
 def allStockLevel(team: String): (String, List[Int]) =
    (team, mapdata.get(team).getOrElse(List.empty))


  //Shows Highest Stock
  def highestStockLevel(stock: String): (String, Int) =
    (stock, mapdata.get(stock).map(_.max).getOrElse(0))

  //Shows the Lowest Stock
  def lowestStockLevel(stock: String): (String, Int) =
  (stock, mapdata.get(stock).map(_.min).getOrElse(0))


  //Show last element in the list, most current
  def currentStockLevel (team: String): (String, Int) = {
    if (team.tail == Nil)
      team.head
    else
      currentStockLevel(ls.tail)
  }
```

Relevant Handler

```
 // handlers for menu options
  def handleOne(): Boolean = {
    mnuShowPoints(currentPoints)
    true
  }
```

Relevant Function

```
  def mnuShowSingleDataStock(f: (String) => (String,Int)) = {
    print("Stock>")
    val data = f(readLine)
    println(s"${data._1}: ${data._2}")
  }
```

The list is being read from txt file

```
    // read data from file
  val mapdata = readFile("data.txt")


 // UTILITY FUNCTIONS
  //GETS THE DATA FROM THE DATA.TXT
  def readFile(filename: String): Map[String, List[Int]] = {
    processInput(Source.fromFile(filename).getLines)
  }
  def processInput(lines: Iterator[String]): Map[String, List[Int]] = {
    Try {
      lines.foldLeft(Map[String, List[Int]]()) { (acc, line) =>

        val splitline = line.split(",").map(_.trim).toList
        acc.updated(splitline.head, splitline.tail.map(_.toInt))
      }
    }.getOrElse {
      println("Sorry, an exception happened.")
      Map()
    }
  }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @marstran Type mismatch, found char, required string int

Comment: It's because `team.head` returns a `Char`. Your `team` parameter is a `String`. The `head` function returns the first element the `String`, which is a `Char`. You do not construct a `(String, Int)` anywhere.

Comment: How would I change it so the first element, the Char, is returned as a string int? Or is there a more efficient way of doing it? @marstran

Comment: your `currentStockLoevel` is currently defined as: give me a `String` and I will return you a pair `(String, Int)` - hence your error.

Comment: I have no idea how you would map the `Char` to a `(String, Int)`. What do you want the string and int to contain?

Comment: The string returns the key of the list, the first letters, e.g. "SK1" and the int I am trying make return a single value, the last element of the tail in the list @marstran

Comment: The key of the list? What is that? You don't have a list anywhere.

Comment: Updated the question, The list is being read from the txt file @marstran

Comment: My point is that `currentStockLevel` takes a single `String` as input, but you say that it takes a list. A `String` is not a `List` (although it can work as an `IndexedSeq[Char]`, but that is probably not what you want to work with).

Comment: The string is simply the head of the list, the list is the tail @marstran

Comment: I am talking about the function `currentStockLevel` here. It takes 1 parameter of type `String`. Lets say this string has the value `Hello`. The head of this string would then be `H`, and the tail would be `ello`. There is no list inside the `currentStockLevel` function. I really don't get what you are talking about.

Comment: Can you reduce your question to a function signature? Example: `lastElement: def f[A, B](map: Map[A, B]): Option[B]`?

Answer (score 0):

if your map data is like:

```
a,1,2
b,2,3
c,4,6
```

then find last number in every entry like:

```
  //Show last element in the list, most current
  def currentStockLevel (list: (String,List[Int]) ): (String, Int) = {
    if (list._2.tail == Nil)
      (list._1,list._2.head)
    else
      currentStockLevel(list._1,list._2.tail)
  }

mapdata.map(currentStockLevel).foreach(println)
```

Or just using key of mapdata:

```
def currentStockLevel (list: String ): (String, Int) = {

    def current(list:  List[Int]):Int = {
      if (list.tail == Nil)
        (list.head)
      else
        current(list.tail)
    }

    val res = mapdata.get(list) match {
      case Some(x: List[Int]) => x
      case _ => List.empty
    }

    (list,current(res))
  }


mapdata.map(x => current(x._1)).foreach(println)
```

Comment: I get an error "Expected type "Any" does not confirm to type Int" @FaigB